# document set saves as document set but then re-opens as a folder

Tags: document-set

When I create a new document set and click save, the document set opens fine. Problem is that when I click back, the document set icon now appears as a folder icon and once clicked, it opens as a folder and no longer a document set. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks
Col